# SFTP server Issue -- Too many open Files on Linux

Tags: linux, sftp

We have SFTP server on linux box.
And every other week we get an error message "Too Many Open Files".
We have to restart the SFTP server every time we get this issue.

Let me know if there is a way to close the opened files automatically with out restarting the SFTP service.

I have set the open file limit to 100,000 files.

Thanks,
Bhargav

Comment: name and version of the daemon would be helpful

Comment: Its Linoma GoAnywhere Service 2.8.0

Comment: For me it seems to be a software bug. As an OS you do not want to close files that are opened by a program. Did you contact support?

Comment: yeah, i have posted it on there forum and trying to contact there support now. When i looked at the open files under proc and process ID, most of  the open files are the pipes which are getting created.

Answer (score 1):

version 2.8.0 of GoAnywhere Services is about a year old and has had quite a few releases/fixes since that time.  The latest release, version 3.2.0 contains fixes for this specific issue. You can see the release notes for the software you are asking about here: http://www.goanywheremft.com/support/release-notes/goanywhere-services

Additionally, more details can be found on the online forum topic you opened for this question:
http://www.goanywheremft.com/forum/post626.html?sid=233959b540891c879ec25ec8fdf4c6ee#p626